# How to use SSL in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

I want to use SSL on Google App Engine. Is there a 3rd-party Python module I must use or can I just use the Google SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should work just fine out of the box, see;

https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Secure_URLs

Answer (score 1):

"Use" SLL for what? Joachim has answered regarding serving your pages over SSL.

If you want an SSL client, then urlfetch allows https URLS. It gives you no control other than the "validate_certificate" boolean parameter, and I don't immediately see any documentation of what CAs/certificates it trusts. Of course it doesn't support any protocol other than HTTPS, but that's in keeping with the fact that in general, GAE does not allow free use of sockets.

Comment: True I wish GAE had some socket freedom. I'm not too clear on those details but I believe that the google server handles all the SSL, with the appconfig just introducing the connection. So there is no specific auth or cert outside of the google domain, in effect they are the provider -- we can request they turn on a secure connection between client and app per url, or not. Nothing more. I think this should be ok. I'm hoping SSL covers channels.